# Git Bash 2.5 cannot connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, windows, git, git-bash

I'm having a really annoying problem to connect to MySQL by Git Bash 2.5 (via Windows on localhost).
Everything works fine trough CMD and Mysysgit.

`$ mysql -u root -proot
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 7
Server version: 5.6.26-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql>`

But, look at this. Git SCM for windows still stuck, blinking the cursor for ever and ever. Have you guys seen this? Anyone can help me?

`$ mysql -u root -proot
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

the solution is provided here:
[Git Bash mysql blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620670/git-bash-mysql-blank)

use this `winpty` before any window command and it works.

```
winpty mysql -u root -proot
```

Answer (score 2):

The [issue 242](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/242) point out:

> this is a known problem (see [`git-for-windows/build-extra/installer`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/43d672f/installer/ReleaseNotes.md#known-issues)):
>
> > Some console programs interact correctly with MinTTY only when called through winpty (e.g. the Python console needs to be started as winpty python instead of just python).
>
> If you do not like that, feel free to choose the installer option not to use MinTTY.
>
> Please note also that Git for Windows is not your "Linux on Windows". It really is supporting Git on Windows and not necessarily mysql.

Using mysql in a docker container (like [`nkratzke/EasyMySQL`](https://github.com/nkratzke/EasyMySQL)) would be easier and provide a more manageable Linux environment.