# Git Bash mysql blank

Tags: mysql, git-bash

I've installed Git (bash?) from www.git-scm.com
I also have a working installation of MySQL. I'm using windows 8.1. The path to my mysql bin directory IS in my path environment variable, and the mysql service IS running.

If i open cmd.exe and type in `mysql -u root` then it logs me in successfully, I get the "welcome to mysql monitor" message, and i can start typing sql away.

However in Git bash, if I type in `mysql -u root` then it just starts a new blank link and doesn't do anything.

If i type in `mysql -?` then i still get the mysql help information. If i type in `mysql start`, I get the `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'start'`.

How can I access mysql properly in git bash?

Please see my crude image explaining my situation below:

[image]

Comment: That sounds like it has actually started the mysql client, but the terminal is behaving the way it would if the login had no TTY (non-interactive session). If you typed a query on the blank line and terminated it correctly, MySQL would probably produce some output as though it was reading the stream from stdin. I don't know much about git bash though to recommend how to correct that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately i'm a beginner at git bash too, and am trying to streamline my environment! I'll keep trying.

Comment: If git-bash is based on MinGW, you may be seeing a symptom of this https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=158 Sorry I don't know more to confirm it.

Comment: It does sound like the issue. I'll just switch between git-bash and cmd for the time being. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ditto this. With no password in git console, I get "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user..." as expected.  With the correct password, nothing happens.  Works fine in windows command prompt.  I do believe it is probably a git console setting, but I couldn't say which. I don't recall this happening on previous git console versions.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I had the same problem with git bash and mysql, and solution to this is to use

```
winpty mysql -u root
```

I guess this is because you are running mysql for windows, using unix environment, and as far as I know winpty should be used for running windows applications in the git bash (not 100% sure, maybe someone can confirm).

Comment: Thanks! This helps.
And if you add the following line to your ~/.bashrc you won't have to enter "winpty" every time you start the mysql console:
`alias mysql="winpty mysql"`

Comment: Thanks! When you need to import files, then do: 
use database_name;
source path/to/file.sql;

Comment: Wow, I'd never heard of this, and it was really helpful!

Comment: This worked but how it does not give you features of linux like Ctrl+r to look in history. Ctrl+A (to go to home). This is as good as invoking windows cmd. Is there a way in which this works like bash prompt.

Comment: OMG. Plenty of hours spent looking for an answer. I’ve signed in to SO just to give my +1. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

**A Quick fix for other users facing that issue too:**

You can create a `.bash_profile` to config git bash, to always use `winpty` by default :

```
cd ~ && echo "alias mysql=\"winpty mysql\"" > .bash_profile
```

if you already have a `.bash_profile` in your user folder use this command instead:

```
cd ~ && echo "alias mysql=\"winpty mysql\"" >> .bash_profile
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem before....
Just use the simple cammand:

```
winpty mysql -u root -p
```

Then press enter and the terminal asks for the password, enter your password and then it connects, the bash to the mysql server.

Answer (score 2):

Create a shortcut in Windows Desktop with this destination:

"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe" -e "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\winpty.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB 10.1\bin\mysql.exe" -uroot -p

Comment: Can you explain that?

Comment: If you install with a local user account (non admin), this could also work:  `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe -e "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\winpty.exe" "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -uroot -p` (note the MySQL or MariaDB path and version, and windows username must be updated)

Comment: This solution works great and you can use ctrl- and ctrl+ to zoom in or zoom out the text size. 
**"fullfolder\mintty.exe" -e "fullfolder\winpty.exe" "fullfolder\mysql.exe" -uroot -p**

Comment: For some reason, my window closes as soon as it opens... this is recent.  Wondering if antivirus is interfering

Comment: Not working for me. I get the same thing as Ignacio.