# Why mysql access doesn't work on git bash?

Tags: mysql, bash, window, git-bash

I'm trying to access mysql using Git Bash and/or ConEmu but it doesn't work.
I'm using the command: `mysql -u root -p`

- **ConEmu** : ask me to enter the password. I write it but nothing happen. (the password is also really randomly hidden with *, some char yes other not, it depends).
- **Git Bash** : after I text `mysql -u root -p` doesn't make anything.
- everything works with normal **windows CMD**.

What do I do wrong guys ?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a terminal issue arising from clashes between git bash (cygwin) and the windows command prompt. A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620670/git-bash-mysql-blank) prompts a number of good answers, [including](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35964412/5729872):

`winpty mysql`

On the 8.0.29 build I have locally, the mysql command line is invoked with the slightly differently named `mysqlsh.exe`, and I can get it to run with

`winpty mysqlsh`

You can alias this command in the usual bash way.

`alias mysql='winpty mysqlsh'`

Comment: This is the way... though I think you have a typo in your alias, that didn't work but `alias mysql='winpty mysql'` did. (Add this to your `~/.bash_aliases` for a more permanent solution).

Comment: In the version I have installed the path to the MysQL shell binary is `<install location>/MySQL/MySQL Shell 8.0/bin/mysqlsh`, but I can imagine this varying by version or install package, so you might be right too.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Linux user and do not have a whole lot experience with Windows.
My assumption is that if you run Windows, then your version of `mysql` that you run within CMD is absolutely different from `mysql` that you run within Git Bash. This is why it will not run as you would expect.

If you have `file` command within Git Bash environment, try running `file $(which mysql)`. In case it is a Linux version and can be run from Git Bash it will output something like this.

```
/usr/bin/mysql: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, fo
r GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=25171134a33827663abd4250e4e33ea524dd3d01, stripped
```